# SearchBar Display Controller not showing UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark on search result

Tags: uisearchdisplaycontroller, searchbar

I am working on check and uncheck of table view cell however my code is working fine without search display controller. When I use Search Bar display controller I am getting search result and when I click on search result details "THERE IS NO CHECK ICON" and If part is not called "if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)" Below is my Code..I am not able to attache my source code.

Only problem is I am not able to add check icon on cell when clicked on cell in search results only..when I remove text from search results I am able to see check icon. Please help

Thanks In advance

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You forgot to post your code below "Below is my Code"

Comment: I am not able to add my source code please someone help me for this.

Comment: You can put code into your question text by indenting each line of code by four spaces. This is much easier to read than screenshots, especially if you condense it to the relevant pieces of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like at the end of your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you are reloading the wrong tableview. See where you wrote `[self.tableView reloadData]`? Try changing that to

```
// At the end of tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath...
[tableView reloadData]  // Reload the tableView that was updated
```

Or, inside of the if condition for checking if it's the search table that was selected...

```
[self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
```